# why i am unable to print array using while loop which is filled using fgets?

Tags: c

```
main()
{       
    FILE *fp;       
    char buff[255];      
    int i;    
    fp = fopen("input.txt", "r");    
    if( fp != NULL )      
    {         
       while ( !feof(fp ) )    
        {
         memset(buff, '\0', sizeof( buff) );
         fgets(buff, 255, (FILE*)fp);
        }
       fclose(fp);
     }       
    i=0;    
    while(  buff[i]!='\0' )    
    {           
       printf ("%s",buff[i]);
       i++;    
    }    
}
```

Comment: what error u getting?

Comment: is your file contain exact 255 bytes?

Comment: `printf("%s",buff[i])` is not good, since `buff[i]` is a `char` not a string.

Comment: what's up with the cast `fgets(buff, 255, (FILE*)fp);` ?? just write `fgets(buff,sizeof(buff),fp);`

Comment: if the file is not opened you get a potential infinite loop since you don't initialize buff

Answer (score 1):

Comment the line containing the while loop `while ( !feof(fp ) )` and replace `%s` with `%c` in `printf`

Answer (score 0):

```
printf ("%s",buff[i]);
```

Should be

```
printf ("%c",buff[i]);
```

Also more good way is

```
char buffer[255];
while(!feof(fp)) {
    if (fgets(buffer,255,fp)) {
        printf("%s\n", buffer);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fgets can be used as below and also you need to use %c instead of %s



 int main()
    {

       FILE *fp;

       char buff[255];

       int i;


       fp = fopen("input.txt", "r");

       if( fp != NULL )
       {   
          while(!feof(fp))
          {   
             memset(buff, '\0', sizeof( buff) );
             fgets(buff, 255, (FILE*)fp);
             puts(buff);
          }   
          fclose(fp);
       }   

       return 0;

    }
```